# How can I develop an ARCore app that can work with older versions of Google Play service for AR?

Tags: android, unity-game-engine, arcore

Please accept my apologies for my poor English skills.
I want to create an ARCore application.
when I run the Hello ARCore example on my Honor 9x I see a message that tell the Google play service for AR needs to be updated to the latest version. the problem is that my device doesn't support the latest version. Can any body tell me how can I solve this problem please?

Comment: Get a new device that supports the latest version. Problem solved.

Comment: Funny answer. But I need to make the app to support devices with older version of Google play service.

Answer (score 0):

Well since there's no way to control what version of Google play service for AR, nor what version of the Android is on your device, then the only thing left to do is find a way to use an older Android Studio, but that's easier said than done. From now on, whenever you set up a new Android Studio, do it on new hardrive or virtual machine so you have the option to go back in time to a previous version. Have been doing that ever since the internet killed the idea of development tools being self-contained on an CD or DVD...